# Debugging json_t object with GDB

Tags: c, json, debugging, gdb

I have a application in C programming which uses jansson library(json library written in C). I'm trying to view value of json_t object in gdb but it just prints

```
(gdb) p jmsg
$20 = (json_t *) 0x69c350
(gdb) p *jmsg
$21 = {type = JSON_OBJECT, refcount = 1}
```

How is it possible to view the value of json_t in gdb.?

Comment: Try (gdb) p jmsg[0]
 
Or

(*jmsg)[0]

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Didnot work. Here is wat happened:`(gdb) p jmsg[0]
$17 = {type = JSON_OBJECT, refcount = 1}
(gdb) p (*jmsg)[0]
Structure has no component named operator[].`

Comment: I was looking at the documentation and I found this construct.
http://www.digip.org/jansson/doc/2.4/apiref.html#json_object_foreach
I believe that if you use the foreach function and print the value you'll be able to see the structure of your JSON object.

Comment: That's true if I change the source code. I want to be able to view json value from gdb and not touch code in any case.

Comment: Why not make a debug function that uses the foreach function and call that debug function using GDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in GDB, you can make function calls directly. Jansson library has a json_dumps(json_t *, int flags) API that returns a char* string of the json_t object.

So while in GDB, just simply do:

```
(gdb) call json_dumps(obj, 0)
```

GDB will then print the string output of your json object.